# Read text or csv file in Javascript and redraw chart

Tags: javascript, csv, reload, txt

I'm new to Javascript and would like to know how to replace data--currently included in a .js file--with a call to read it from a txt or csv file. Thus, instead of ...

```
const chart = some_application.createChart(document.body, {width: 500, height: 400});

const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries();

lineSeries.setData([
  { time: '2020-07-11', value: 90.11 },
  { time: '2020-07-12', value: 95.43 },
  { time: '2020-07-13', value: 96.24 },
  { time: '2020-07-14', value: 91.81 },
  { time: '2020-07-15', value: 94.33 },
  { time: '2020-07-16', value: 87.41 },
  { time: '2020-07-17', value: 93.33 },
  { time: '2020-07-18', value: 85.24 },
  { time: '2020-07-19', value: 84.39 },
  { time: '2020-07-20', value: 78.83 },
]);
```

... I'd like to place the 10 data rows "{ time: ... }, ..." in a txt or csv file, let's say, *time_value.txt* or *time_value.csv*.

b) Is there a way to load the file again when new data arrives and the data file is updated, and redraw the chart?

This file is going to run embedded in another application, and it would be ideal to create a solution with the minimum of dependencies on other libraries. Thus, if it could run on very basic standard Javascript commands it would be good for compatibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use a combination of `setInterval` and `fetch` to request the data at regular intervals. There are no external dependencies for these, so you could do something like this:

```
        // handle the new data. For now, just parse the JSON and log to the console.
        function setData(data) {
            data.forEach(el => {
                console.log(el);
            });
        }
        // function to retrieve the data from the server.
        async function fetchData() {
            console.log("fetching data");
            await fetch('textFile.json')
            .then(resp=>{
                if (resp.ok) {
                    resp.json()
                    .then(newData=>setData(newData));
                }
            });
        }
        // setInterval calls fetchData every 10 seconds.
        let interval = setInterval(fetchData, 10000);
```

So, provided your server places the new data in the file on the web site, this code can update the chart every ten seconds. This snippet assumes JSON format data, but you can play with that.

The disadvantage here is that the client will have to wait up to ten seconds (or whatever period you choose) to get the new data. If the data changes infrequently that might not matter. If data changes frequently and/or you have a large client base, this might not work for you.

If latency is an issue then you can use a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) to have the server notify the workstation of new data, but that requires new code on the server to handle it.

Comment: Thanks, Tangentially Perpendicular. Tried to upvote but not allowed until I have more points.